# How to read SecurityToken and Signature value from Soap Request

Tags: c#, xml, linq, soap

I have soap request captured

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IService/GetAccountsData</a:Action>
    <h:SecurityToken xmlns:h="http://tempuri.org/">SEC00001</h:SecurityToken>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:d54052d7-fed7-40f4-9b3f-f857d0804ffb</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <CustomerCredential xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CustomerID>C001</CustomerID>
      <RuleId>2.1</RuleId>
      <Signature i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </CustomerCredential>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need to read the SecurityToken and Signature value in c#.

I am trying with below code but not able to read the SecurityToken and Signature value.

```
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;

var elements = from c in doc.Descendants(ns + "Header")
               select c;
```

Please post your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following solution using XPath expressions. Consider this code :

```
    string filename = "SOAP.xml";
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(filename);
    XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
    // use XmlNamespaceManager to resolve ns prefixes
    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("h", "http://tempuri.org/");
    // use XPath expression to select XML nodes
    XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("//h:SecurityToken",manager);
    if ( nodes.MoveNext() )
        Console.WriteLine(nodes.Current.ToString());
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Empty Element");
    // and now for the Signature Element, without ns prefix
    nodes = navigator.Select("//Signature", manager);
    if (nodes.MoveNext())
        Console.WriteLine(nodes.Current.ToString());
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Empty Element");
```

For further reading, see also MSDN docs for class XPathNavigator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k4x060d.aspx

Comment: I am able to read "SecurityToken" and "Signature" value using this code. Can we read namespace from soap file itself instead of  `manager.AddNamespace("h", "http://tempuri.org/");`

Comment: You could select a node without referring to its ns prefix like so : `XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("//*[local-name() = 'SecurityToken']", manager);` If you still need the ns name itself, you can then retrieve it this way : `nodes.Current.NamespaceURI`

Comment: This solution is really helpful and i am able to get the required values.